# Warning: React does not recognize the `previousStep` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChatBot from 'react-simple-chatbot';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

class Form extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // some other states
      file: ''
    };
  }
  
  onDrop(acceptedFiles){
    var file = acceptedFiles[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const fileAsBinaryString = reader.result;
      this.setState({
        file: fileAsBinaryString
      });
      
      //console.log(fileAsBinaryString);
    }

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

    //console.log(file);
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <ChatBot
        steps={[
          {
            id: '1',
            message: 'You can add custom components',
            trigger: '2',
          },
          {
            id: '2',
            component: (
              <div>
                 <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)} />
              </div>
            ),
            end: true,
          },
        ]}
      />
    )
  
  }

}
```

[image: Warnings]I am trying to use react-dropzone within react-simple-chatbot, but when I upload a file it shows 2 warnings:

1. `React does not recognize the previousStep prop on a DOM element.`
2. `React does not recognize the triggerNextStepenter image description here prop on a DOM element.`

I am able to find similar problems but their solutions are not working out for me. How should I make it work?

Edit: I have added an example similar to my approach.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Seems like `t` is a custom tag, "User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized", this can be a possible reason for Unknown Prop Warning

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dear your question is not not clear to me as it lacks lots of information,It would have better if you put your code here. I don't know did you follow react-dropzone documentation. In their documentation they cleared how to use it in your application. Try to do below procedure. In my case it is working without showing any warning.

```
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'
//OTHERS IMPORT FILE
// ... ... ...
class AddEmployee extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            photo: ""
        }
    }
    // OTHERS FUNCTIONS
    // ... ... ....
    onDrop(files) {
        const file = files.find(f => f)
        let reader = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        reader.onload = () => {
            this.setState({
                photo: reader.result,
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // OTHERS DIV
            // ... ... ... ...
            <div className="dropzone">
                <Dropzone onDrop={(e) => this.onDrop(e)}>
                    {this.state.photo != "" ? <img width={195} height={195} src={this.state.photo} /> : <p>Try dropping some photo here or click to select files to upload</p>
                    }
                </Dropzone>
            </div>

            // OTHERS DIV
            // ... ... ... ...
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am facing the problem when the same dropzone code is returned using react-simple-chatbot, otherwise, it is working out just fine.